# Access refused to the exchange created

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am new to rabbitmq using c#. We are trying to create an API for epex spot it uses AMQP in Transport label protocol and uses Rabbitmq for this.

I am able to connect to the epex spot's server using the credential provided.
`ConnectionFactory factory = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory();`
able to create channel

```
using (IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (IModel channel = conn.CreateModel())
    {
```

But when ever I try to DeclareExchange or DeclareQueue, I get error stating:

> The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=403, text="ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'M7.broadcastQueue.username' in vhost 'app' refused for user 'username'", classId=60, methodId=40

If I try to contact epexspot and ask for permission they say we have all the permission necessary. Can you guys please help how I can fix this issue or if anyone has faces similar issue before?

Answer (score 6):

Your permissions are not set correctly. This command must be run to do so:

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p app username '.*' '.*' '.*'
```

Whomever "epexspot" is didn't set them correctly, or tried to limit the read / write / configure permission for that user.

I'm assuming [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/LguUM1weBVI/reLeo88QAAAJ) is your message as well. When this is resolved, please follow up in all the places you have asked this question with details about the resolution so that others can learn from it.

Comment: Note: using RabbitMQ GUI for publishing test messages I first got `Access refused.`, then after using `set_permissions` I got `403 ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'XXXX in vhost '/' refused for user 'admin'` - I had to reissue the command with double quotes (Windows env, standard CMD): `rabbitmqctl set_permissions admin ".*" ".*" ".*"`

Comment: Well, yes. Windows has different parsing rules than POSIX shells.

Answer (score 0):

While connecting to the server, few important information were missing. Information like exchange were not provided. 
 these information grated the authorization part due to which this error kept raising.

Thank you

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue! What other information did you have to include for it to work?